# iMessage App can't send customed message with GIF

Tags: ios, gif, ios10, imessage

I have a problem about imessage app: I want to send GIF message with some customed info, and when tap on the sent message cell the app can navigate to Expanded style.

In the first time I used MSStickerView, the GIF animated normally, but can't add custom info and when tap on the sent message cell the app can't navigate to Expanded style. So it doesn't work.

I tried another way: construct the message manually

```
NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *queryItems = [NSMutableArray new];
NSURLQueryItem *item = [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"key" value:@"keyValue"]; //It's the customed info
[queryItems addObject:item];
components.queryItems = queryItems;
MSMessageTemplateLayout *layout = [[MSMessageTemplateLayout alloc] init];
layout.mediaFileURL = @"localFileURL";  //local animated image url
MSMessage *message = [[MSMessage alloc] initWithSession:[MSSession new]];
message.layout = layout;
```

and then use activeConversation to insert message:

```
self.activeConversation insertMessage:message completionHandler
```

It turn out that the GIF can't animate, but when tap on the sent message cell the app can navigate to Expanded style.

Dose anyone know how to send GIF message with some customed info, and when tap on the sent message cell the app can navigate to Expanded style?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?I am also stuck on same issue.